# Favicon not displaying in Angular 2

Tags: angular, favicon

I have used the below html code to display the favicon icon in my Angular 2 application

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./images/favicon.png" />
```

But, it's not displaying in any browser. I have clicked in the href link and it's referring to the correct path and opening the image properly.

Please let me know whether I am missing any other thing.

> Small Update:  I am using the angular with webpack and just now i have
>   seen using the sql lite manager and found that the favicon itself is not being loaded when the application started up.

[image]

> my port 8425 is not there

I am not getting why its not being loaded itself

Answer (score 22):

**2 steps fix**

> Step-1 : Put the icon file inside the **assets** folder

In Angular application, all the user files are served from assets folder only.
Though the default icon of angular app lives inside the src folder, but user's file will not be included if it's outside of assets folder.

> Step-2 : **Update** the `<link>` element with proper attributes

```html
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./assets/Images/Logo.png">
```

Comment: Step 1 was important. Misses in many other answers on this topic.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info about Step 1.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `>` which is added just before the `href`:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.png" />
<!--                                          here  ^-->
```

Comment: Sorry, i dont know how it got pasted like that actually its like   <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./images/favicon.png" />

Comment: Okay! try removing the `.` which is in the href.

Comment: removed still not working do i need to rebuild or clear my browsing data and cache

Comment: _rebuild_ is better option. Try with absolute path then move with root relative.

Comment: still da same ??